# Spring Social facebook connection is persisted across sessions

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I've successfully integrated Spring Social, but I am getting back the same facebook template across sessions.

Consider the following time line

- Server restart
- User A logs in using facebook
- User A goes to another page on the site
- User B logs in using facebook on a different computer
- User B goes to another page on the site

The access token in the last step is same of the User A. I think I need to customize the behaviour of `ConnectionRepository` but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: You can do it any way, but you didn't try it.